# how to use exec() to run a c program from another c program

Tags: c, process, exec

i've been trying to use execvp to run a c program but it always seems to fail.

from main.c

```
int main() {
char* args[] = {"2", "1"};
    if(execvp("trial.c", args) == -1) {
        printf("\nfailed connection\n");
    }
```

from trial.c

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
printf("working");
return 1;
}
```

I think i tried every way to possibly represent that file location in the exec() and it always results in "failed connection".

Comment: It looks like you're trying to execute something that is not (yet) an executable?

Comment: Have you tried executing 'trial.c' from the command line to see if it possibly *could* work?

Comment: How do you compile those two C source files, .c files?

Comment: Doing *exactly* what lead to you getting "*failed connection*"?

Comment: "*`if(execvp(...))`*" No need for the `if()`, as the members of the `exec*()` family of functions only return on error.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to `execvp` expects the name of an executable file.  What you've passed it is the name of a source file.  You need to first compile trial.c, then pass the name of the compiled executable to `execvp`.

Regarding the second parameter to `execvp`, the last element in the array **must** be `NULL`.  That's how it knows it reached the end of the list.  Also,  by convention the first parameter to a program is the name of the program itself.

So first compile trial.c:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o trial trial.c
```

Then modify how to call it in main.c:

```
int main() {
    char* args[] = { "trial", "2", "1", NULL };
    if(execvp("trial", args) == -1) {
        printf("\nfailed connection\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding! I did the changes you mentioned but i am still getting "failed connection". did anything need to be changed on the trail.c file? my current main.c is: `char* args[] = {"player", NULL};` `if(execvp("player", args) == -1) {
            printf("\nfailed connection\n");
        }`

Comment: @josephcornell Use `perror` instead of `printf` to print the error messages.  That will tell you why it failed.

Answer (score 1):

First argument for `execvp` is path to executable.
You need to build the executable for `trial.c` and pass the path of the executable to `execvp`.

```
if(execvp("---path to executable---/ExecTrial", args) == -1) {
    printf("\nfailed connection\n");
}
```

If you don't pass the executable path, `execvp` will search the executable in the colon-separated list of directory pathnames specified in the
       `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to call [`execvp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) on a source file then this is not what this function does. The first argument is expected to be a path of an executable. If you want to run the program which *trial.c* is the source of, you should build (compile and such) it first. For example like this:

```
$ gcc -o trial trial.c
```

Then call `execvp()` on the your newly created executable instead of the source file:

```
if(execvp("trial", args) == -1) { //...
```

Answer (score 0):

trial.c is not a valid executable file.  C is not a scripting or interpreted language; you cannot run C source files directly.  A C program must be compiled and linked into an executable.